# When will a person falling into a black hole be crashed by tidal forces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, acceleration, tidal-effect

Assume that a person can resist $30g\approx 300\frac m{s^2}$ (remark: the record is actually at 46.2). I want to solve for the distance $r$ at which a $1.5m$ tall slim person falling radially into a blackhole of given Schwarzschild radius $R_S$ is destroyed by tidal forces.

From the geodesic equation (as in Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry (5.64), p.208), I have that

\begin{align}\left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2 &= E^2 - \left(1-\frac {R_S}r\right)\\
& = \left(1-\frac {R_S}r\right)^2\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2 - \left(1-\frac {R_S}r\right)\end{align}

For $t=\tau$, this yields

$$v(r):=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac {R_S}r\right)^2 -\left(1-\frac {R_S}r\right)}$$

As for the average acceleration on the body, I have that

$$a = \frac{v(\text{feet}) - v(\text{head})}{1.5m/v(\text{body CM})}$$

Then, if the feet are at $R_S+x$, the CM will be at $R_S+x+.75m$ and the head at $R_S+x+1.5m$. I can input all this into the equations, but then I don't know how to simplify and solve for $x$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: $t$ and $\tau$ cannot be set equal, and your expression for $a$ does not have the right dimensions to be acceleration.

Comment: Acceleration and tidal force are two different things. You could have 30g of acceleration with no tidal force, for example.

Comment: Rodrigo, the answer depends on how much force a normal human being can withstand without being pulled apart.  Obviously, such information is very difficult to come by, as it would be extremely unethical and illegal to obtain this information.

Comment: To calculate tidal acceleration use [geodesic deviation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation). Also, Misner, Thorne,Wheeler §32.6 has a solution.

Comment: Thank you for providing the exact location in MTW!  I've been googling this for a while without success.  Interesting that for Schwarzchild metric the stretch result is identical to the Newtonian result. I will have to investigate if it is also true for the compression.